# Gesture Overlay on SplashScreen

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-gesture

I'm trying to use a gesture overlay on a activity that is used as a splash screen.

The problem is when I : `gOverlay = (GestureOverlayView) this.findViewById(R.id.gOverlay);` , gOverlay is null.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:gravity="center" android:background="#000000"
android:weightSum="1">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.11">
    <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/gOverlay"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="#000000"
        >
    </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
 </RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

This is Splash java code:

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    /** set time to splash out */

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        Duration = extras.getString("Duration");
    }
    welcomeScreenDisplay = 4000;
    try {
        welcomeScreenDisplay = Integer.parseInt(Duration);
    } catch (Exception x) {
    }

    gLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);

    if (!gLibrary.load()) {
        finish();
    }
    gOverlay = (GestureOverlayView) this.findViewById(R.id.gOverlay);
    gOverlay.setGestureVisible(false);
    gOverlay.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);

    /** create a thread to show splash up to splash time */
    Thread welcomeThread = new Thread() {
        int wait = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                super.run();

                while (wait < welcomeScreenDisplay) {
                    sleep(100);
                    wait += 100;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("EXc=" + e);
            } finally {

                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    welcomeThread.start();

}
```

**What i'm trying to do is :
1. When user presses back button Splash screen will show. 
2. This splash screen will be on the screen for n seconds
3. If the user draw a 'L' on the splash screen, implicit on Gesture Overlay, main activity will .finish()**

Thanks

Comment: Please add the source, where you assign `gOverlay`. Are you sure, you inflated the right layout?

Comment: Show the code where do you declare `gOverlay` (if you do).

Comment: Don't do splash screens. You're wasting your users' time *every* time they start your app. Your app probably isn't worth it.

Comment: Splashscreens CAN be useful. If you need to do some work before your app can be started. But then it is more a loading screen.

Comment: What is the name of "This is my XML"? Is this the 'R.layout.splash'?

Comment: public class Splash2 extends Activity implements GestureOverlayView.OnGesturePerformedListener {


    private String Duration;
    private int welcomeScreenDisplay;
    private GestureLibrary gLibrary;

    GestureOverlayView gOverlay;

Comment: this is before the onCreate method

Comment: splash2.xml is the name of the XML

Comment: Please see edited post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments you gave, it seems that you are inflating the wrong layout.

You said, the layout containing the `GestureOverlayView` is named splash2.

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
```

But instead you are inflating splash, not splash2. If splash.xml does not contain the `GestureOverlayView` with `android:id="@+id/gOverlay"`, then requesting gOverlay from splash, will throw a nullpointer.

Changing `setContentView()` in your activity to following should help:

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash2);
```

Comment: I didn't see that I used another Content View. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem. But be aware of what @323go said. Most splashscreens annoy users. So avoid them, if possible.

Comment: I will. Do u have any idea how to .finish main activity from splash screen?

Comment: Normaly you would finish Activity A right after starting Activity B. `startActivity(intent); finish();` would be it.

Comment: No, I want to finish SplashScreen and Main Activity in some condition : like -> User draws 'L' letter on SplashScreen

Comment: If you want to close your splashscreen aswell, it can be done with `startActivityForResult()`. But you might want to open another question for further discussion